# Dúvida com Rotas no Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quando se criar um `Controller` é criado um :

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Mas neste `Controller`, caso tenha um novo `Action` sendo necessário um parâmetro, se o usuário tentar abrir este link vai gerar um erro. Existe alguma forma de evitar este erro quando a 'View' esta enviando um parametro desta forma:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <a href="/Relatorios/ListaSelecionado/@item.IDJOGOCAIXA" class="list-group-item">
           Número :  @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.IDJOGOCAIXA) - 
        </a>

    }


public ActionResult ListaSelecionado(int id)
   {
        return View();
   }
```

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto está correto. Qual o erro que você está tendo? Pode colocá-lo na sua pergunta também?

Comment: Esta correto, mais se o usuário tentar abri a página de forma direta vai gera um erro

Comment: Sim, mas qual erro?

Comment: modifique a sua `Action` para `ListaSelecionado(int? id)` ou `ListaSelecionado(int id = 0)` e faça os devidos tratamentos para `null` ou `zero`

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

> Mas neste Controller, caso tenha um novo Action sendo necessário um parâmetro, se o usuário tentar abrir este link vai gerar um erro. Existe alguma forma de evitar este erro?

Não entendi o que você quis dizer com isso, mas se você não envia o parâmetro para a *Action*, vai dar erro mesmo.

Se estamos falando de um método assim:

```
public ActionResult ListaSelecionado(int id) { ... }
```

Espera-se uma rota assim:

```
http://teste:12345/MeuController/ListaSelecionado/1
```

Isto considerando que seu método é `GET`. Se for `POST`, `id` só será preenchido se o envio for feito a partir de um formulário que contenha um `<input>` chamado `id`, ou ainda a requisição tenha no corpo de dados um campo chamado `id`.

---

**EDIT**

Note que o erro que você está tendo diz claramente que a *Action* está pedindo um parâmetro inteiro chamado `id` na rota. Por isso, acessar:

```
http://teste:12345/MeuController/ListaSelecionado/
```

Vai dar erro, porque `id` não está preenchido. Agora, se você passar qualquer número depois de `ListaSelecionado/`:

```
http://teste:12345/MeuController/ListaSelecionado/234
```

Vai funcionar, por mais que o Id não exista.

Comment: eu estou explicando melhor na minha pergunta! agradeço

Comment: Ok, eu entendi a sua resposta, eu também sei que se eu passar qualquer número não vai dar erro, o problema e se o usuário tenta entra diretamente nesta página após a mesma esta gravada no seu computador, neste caso teria alguma rota para direcionar o usuário informando que não foi possível ou direcionar ele para a index?

Comment: Ah, bom. Aí pra você não deixar ele entrar diretamente pelo endereço, use `[HttpPost]` em cima da *Action*, mas aí você teria que embutir um formulário no link.

Comment: Ah bom, você agora me deu uma super ideia, mais como usar este link embutindo e direcionar o usuário para uma página especifica, ou é possível uma página de erro

Comment: Isto seria outra pergunta.

Comment: ok, vou vou fazer uma nova pergunta